# What is the function of から in 昼間から?

Tags: grammar, translation, particles, particle-から

I found a phrase that contains 昼間から but I am not sure if I understand the から function correctly:

> またこの子は**昼間から**ゴロゴロして

I believe that it should roughly translate to "This child is being lazy all day again".

But when I tried to understand all the parts of this sentence, I can't make anything else out of 昼間から other than "from daytime", and it doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

What am I missing?

Edit: Is this meaning/use documented anywhere?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65295/use-of-%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89-rather-than-%e3%81%ab-in-%e7%9c%9f%e3%81%a3%e6%98%bc%e9%96%93%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89

Comment: I stumbled across that same post, but since they are talking about 真っ昼間から as if it was an expression by itself with certain connotations, I am not sure if the same could be applied to 昼間から. Does it have the same connotations that could be translated as "from such a time as would normally be considered too early"?

Comment: 「朝っぱら**から** 」に似てるよね。（この「ぱら」って何だろう‥？）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They assume that children should not start gaming, reading comics or doing other non-productive things like `ゴロゴロする` **from** the morning, noon or any time in the daytime.

[Edit]

After thinking for hours, I realized it's not right to translate `から` into 'from' here. The feeling or sense of `から` seems different than 'from'. It's interesting to know that "*from* the daytime" doesn't sound right in English.

`から` comes with anything like morning, noon, daytime, night, today, yesterday and so on. The thing is, you can say `Xから` even if it *is* time of X. So something like "*from* the daytime = in the daytime" happens in Japanese.

In your sentence, the kid started `ゴロゴロする` in the daytime AND the speaker is also saying that in the daytime. Also, yes, `から` can make connotations like "from such a time".

Other examples:

> [朝から]{あさから}[勉強]{べんきょう}するの？
>
> 1. [said in the morning] Are you going to study (start studying) now?
> 2. Do you study (start studying) in the morning?
> 3. Will you study (start studying) in the morning?

> [朝]{あさ}**に**[勉強]{べんきょう}するの？
>
> 1. Do you study in the morning?
> 2. Will you study in the morning?

Comment: But can 昼間 be interpreted as morning/noon? I haven't seen that definition anywhere

Comment: Yes, because it has connotation as you said in the comment. I don't know if "from the daytime" or "in the daytime" is more natural and fitting here.

Comment: What I find odd is that I don't see this documented anywhere. Since this came from subtitles out of a spoken dialogue I am starting to wonder if they really meant to say ひるまえ instead of ひるま, and that reflected as a gramatical error on the phrase

Comment: Here 昼間から is similar to 真っ昼間から/朝っ腹から and they are commonly used. You can find them in the dictionary: [真っ昼間](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/12910/meaning/m0u/), [朝っ腹](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%9C%9D%E3%81%A3%E8%85%B9/)

Comment: I've seen the 真っ昼間 entry in the dictionary, in this case I find it odd that there is basically no reference anywhere about the [昼間から](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/12907/meaning/m0u/%E6%98%BC%E9%96%93/) expression specifically. It makes me wonder whether it is correct to use it or it is some kind of incorrect expression akin to "Laismo" in Spanish. People use it, for sure, but it is not right to do so. At this point I am just looking for a reliable source about this just out of curiosity.

Comment: I still don't know what makes you think "昼間から" is an incorrect expression. It's just "from + time", grammatically correct and nothing special.

Comment: It is that it refers to a whole timeframe rather than a point in time so it would make sense to interpret is as "during the day", but から is not documented anywhere to be used with the meaning of "during". On the original translation 昼間から was referred as "from the morning", but again I found that using 昼間 as "morning" is not documented anywhere. 昼間から as a whole expression in itself is also not documented on the dictionary, all that makes me think that it was a slip while speaking due to the similarity of 昼間 and 昼前. "From the daytime" or "from the whole day" doesn't sound right.

Comment: @Aridez I recommend you drop the English parallel because it’s perfectly natural in Japanese and not a slip. This 〜から accepts things that are strictly ranges (昼間、朝、早朝、etc). The implication is that you are doing(/starting) something earlier than expected. The opposite expression is also fine, eg （夜/夜中/etc)まで何してんの？, which implies you are doing something later (for longer) than expected — this also doesn’t have a syntactically identical parallel in English.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie absolutely, I understand that and I really appreciate the explanations! I see that every particle has a lot of different meanings on its dictionary entry because there is no 1 to 1 translation from such a different language, but in this case what has me puzzled is that I can't really find, let's say, a "textbook explanation" about this particular case. The meaning conveyed by this expression is not listed, so I found it very odd and even checked some J-J dictionaries with no luck.

Comment: Have you searched just `から` instead of `Xから`? You can find it in every J-J dictionary as in: `1 動作・作用の起点を表す。 ... ㋑時間的起点を示す。「会議は午後1時から始める」「朝から強い風が吹いている」` [source](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89)

Comment: @Satoshi The problem I see is that in this case we are not marking a point in time, it's から should be used to mark a point in time, it's rather a timeframe. And when going to the other side, as far as I'm concerned 昼間 is never defined as something that could be taken as a point in time, instead its the whole day.

Comment: The thing is that any time range can be seen as a point if you zoom out far enough. 昨日からずっと仕事してる is fine, right? But 昨日 is technically referring to an entire 24 hour time range. But what is salient in the sentence is its interpretation as a “start point”. Same with 先週, 先月, etc. 昼間 also works fine, and its “start point” interpretation is “since it is bright out”. (*Not* “since the exact moment it became bright out (daybreak)”, but rather a more zoomed out interpretion when the precision doesn’t matter, just like 昨日から doesn’t mean from 00:00 yesterday)

Comment: BTW, even in English you can say “since the middle of the day” and it’s fine, even though you don’t mean exactly 12:00 *or* the entirety of some precise range like 10pm-3pm, but rather the implication is that precision is being omitted and everything is getting bucketed into “beginning, middle, end”. So this seems like a common phenomenon in natural language interpretation of time ranges, and I detect nothing unusual about the Japanese (except the earlier point about the 〜から in your question not *exactly* mapping to “since” due it being idiomatic, but that is unrelated to the time range issue)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @DariusJahandarie! That really gave me a bit of perspective with the use of から in this context, I'll mark it as solved.